# Would I be able to check if the time is between 12:00 and 13:00 using datetime?

Tags: python, python-datetime

Would I be able to get datetime to tell me if the time is in range of 12:00 to 1300

I have tried variations of things like:

```
import datetime
current_time = datetime.datetime.now().time()
if current_time from 12:00 and 13:00:
    print("In time")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compare against other `datetime.time()` objects:

```
if datetime.time(12) <= current_time <= datetime.time(13):
```

This uses *comparison chaining*, the above is basically the same expression as:

```
if datetime.time(12) <= current_time and current_time <= datetime.time(13):
```

but the `current_time` expression is evaluated just once.

I gave `datetime.time()` just the hour component; the minutes then default to `0`:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.time(12)
datetime.time(12, 0)
```